# applying a mouse hover code at jquery ready call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i tried to apply this code:

```
nextText: '<img src="images/nextImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/overnextImgBtn.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/nextImgBtn.png '">',

prevText: '<img src="images/prevImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/hoverprevImgBtn.png '" onmouseout="this.src='images/prevImgBtn.png '">'
```

to this ready call function of **jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 1050,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: false,
        mode: 'horizontal',
        video: true,
        useCSS: false,
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        speed: 2000,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        nextText: '<img src="images/nextImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src='
        images / hovernextImgBtn.png '" onmouseout="this.src='
        images / nextImgBtn.png '">',
        prevText: '<img src="images/prevImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src='
        images / hoverprevImgBtn.png '" onmouseout="this.src='
        images / prevImgBtn.png '">'
    });
});
```

Comment: create a fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just syntactically wrong, you need to escape the quotes. even though it's not the nicest solution, it should probably fix your problem:

```
nextText: '<img src="images/nextImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'images/overnextImgBtn.png \'" onmouseout="this.src=\'images/nextImgBtn.png \'">',

prevText: '<img src="images/prevImgBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'images/hoverprevImgBtn.png \'" onmouseout="this.src=\'images/prevImgBtn.png \'">'
```

Gena's solution is should probably work, and is probably the nicest solution. this one should work also

```
nextText: '<img src="images/nextImgBtn.png" id="slider-next">',
prevText: '<img src="images/prevImgBtn.png" id="slider-prev">
```

and in your css:

```
#slider-prev:hover{
  src:url(images/hoverprevImgBtn.png)
}
#slider-next:hover{
  src:url(images/hovernextImgBtn.png)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, about gena the id slider-next and prev are span tags which holds a link tag and my images can't apply css hover cause i think slider-next and prev span only accepts text so better do it on an img tag with hover code, well hereandnow thanks so as gena

Answer (score 0):

Well, buddy. i think you're just setting text.
Actually who know what does this widget accepts there, probably it's a TEXT for elements with selectors:

```
nextSelector: '#slider-next',
prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
```

you better try the CSS solution

```
 #slider-next:hover{
    src:url(images/hovernextImgBtn.png)
 }
```